# how to go a prticular div using anchor tab in same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want make my website which can be horizontally rotated. But here I want go a specific 'div' usnig anchor tab. Here is my code

```
<div class="horizon scroll">
        <div id="header">
        <div style="height: 60px; width:750px;left:10%;position:relative;">
            <ul>
                <li style="float:left; "> <a href="#home">Home</a> </li>
                <li style="float:left; "> <a href="#pro">Products</a> </li>
                <li style="float:left; "> <a href="#fly">Services</a> </li>
                <li style="float:left; "> <a href="#baloon">About Us</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="front scroll">

        <h1 class="intro">Scroll down</h1>

        <div id="home" class="panel1 page">
            <h2 style="margin: 40px 40px 30px 20px;">Products</h2>
            <p style="margin: 0px 30px 30px 30px;">
                The hot air balloon is the oldest successful human-carrying flight technology. It is part of a class of aircraft known as balloon aircraft.
            </p>    
        </div>

        <div id="pro" class="panel2 page">
            <h2 style="margin: 40px 40px 30px 20px;">Sevices</h2> 
            <p style="margin: 0px 30px 30px 30px;">
                A hot air balloon consists of a bag called the envelope that is capable                 </p>
        </div>

        <div  id ="fly" class="panel3 page">
            <h2 style="margin: 40px 40px 30px 20px;">Education</h2>
            <p style="margin: 0px 30px 30px 30px;">
                As with all aircraft, hot air balloons cannot fly beyond the             </p>
        </div>

        <div  name= "kala" id="baloon" class="panel4 page">
            <a ><h2 style="margin: 40px 40px 30px 20px;">About Us</h2></a>
            <p style="margin: 0px 30px 30px 30px;">
            Beginning during the mid-1970s, balloon envelopes have been made
            </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here Id is not working to go to a particular Div. I can I do instead of this Id?
Thank You.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understood your question. If you want to go to a specific tab through anchor it already works on jquery tabs. Just set `http://website.com/page.html#pro` will work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the body height of a page is less than the height of the view rectangle, or when the offset between scroll hight and view rectangle height is lower than the scroll amount necessary to scroll to the identified element, then no scrolling will occur.